# RedBeanPHP не получает данные из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Дело в том, что я использую RedBeanPHP. И я строю запросы таким образом:

```php
$userID = $_GET['id'];  
    R::selectDatabase('database');
    $userDataID = R::findOne('post', 'user_id = ?', [$userID]);
    $postName = $userDataID->title;
    $postContent = $userDataID->content;
    $postTags = $userDataID->metaTags;

    echo "данные поста";
```

Но echo работает только с запросами к БД, где названия столбцов состоят из букв в одном регистре. Например, `$postName = $userDataID->title;` — echo выводит переменную $postName. А вот `$postTags = $userDataID->metaTags;` echo не выводит переменную $postTags. Поменять в БД столбцы я не могу.

Comment: а как поля у таблицы называются ?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему. finfOne(); получает данные из таблицы как объект. Чтобы представить этот объект как массив, нужно использовать export `$arrayUserDataID = $userDataID->export();` и из переменной $arrayUserDataID можно получать данные как из массива - $arrayUserDataID['title']